# issue with Java Intent

Tags: java, android

i try to make an intent which is used to go to a 2nd activity. however when i try to click on it, it makes my application crash.

here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mButtonCommande;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButtonCommande=findViewById(R.id.buttonAccessCommande);
            mButtonCommande.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openCommandeActivity();
                }
            });

    }

    public void openCommandeActivity() {//cette méthode me sert à envoyer vers l'activité commande
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommandeActivity.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

idk where it keeps crashing and i need help.

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declared the target activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
In your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following inside the `<application>` element:

```
<activity android:name=".CommandeActivity"/>
```

Comment: Why not add this as a comment?

Comment: how can you declare it in the manifest?